# Spark causes a memory error when running DBSCAN source using scala. How can we solve this?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, dbscan

We used 100,000 kits.
The version of spark is 1.6.1 and scala is 2.1.0.
How can I fix memory errors and get good results?

[image]

Comment: Try ELKI with indexing instead of Spark.

Answer (score 3):

The various DBSCAN addons for Spark are all problematic.

Confer this report:

> Neukirchen, Helmut. "Survey and Performance Evaluation of DBSCAN Spatial Clustering Implementations for Big Data and High-Performance Computing Paradigms." (2016).

For JVM languages like Scala, it should be easy to call e.g. ELKI and get a quite good performance.